Advertising in Bluetooth as a single device and le audio
regarding the subject of LE AUDIO, I read about coordinated set where the devices in th the master connects to each device in the set (e.g earbud left and right)
I noticed that some earbuds that supports le audio, advertise as one single device (I believe that means they're already paired)
In such case, if the master connects to only one earbud (primary) and the secondary receives audio from primary,
or for example in case of qualcomm TWS mirroing, where the secondary earbud is aware of the connection and eavesdropping but there's no link between this earbud and the master, how the concept of le audio works? I understood that the idea is, to have two CIS'S streams for each earbud, such that the master connects directly to each earbud in le audio.so if only one earbud renders the audio to the other, what's the idea? (they claim to support le audio)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
